# Android debug on device fail connect to port 23

Tags: android

I have app client connect to server on port 23. I was run debug on Samsung mobile phone.
I connect to server throught internet. My app work well with Wifi connection. But when i change to use cellular data network, the port 23 fail. My app have multi client, other client work fine on other port than 23.

Please help me this case.

Comment: Talk to the cellular data network provider and ask them. They do not necessarily have to support every possible port.

Comment: I have other ios app. It work fine with same cellular network

Comment: I just change port to 25. It's working. But I still want to know reason. Anybody have idea?